# How to email an icalendar (ics) file

Tags: email, attachment, icalendar

Im developing a RoR application, i'm using Ri_Cal to generate an ics file, i want to email this file as an attachment so people who receive it can add the events I'm sending to their calendar. I have tried attaching the file in an email but when i open it with Mail.app in OSX it doesn't automatically ask if i want to add the event. I have to download etc. How can i archive this to be automatically?

Comment: When you say automatically do you mean as soon as they open the E-Mail?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your ICS file has METHOD:PUBLISH or METHOD:REQUEST. The latter should trigger asking.

Answer (score -2):

I want do this with mi app but Zimbra never detect `METHOD:PUBLISH`
When I use Thunderbird for invite, Zimbra detect icalendar without problems.